# Network Intrusion Detection System in Java..!

Tags: java, security, networking, jpcap

I am planning on implementing a NIDS (Net Intrusion Detection System) in the Java programming language.

After searching, I found two libraries for this.

1) Jpcap

2) jNetPcap

Which one should I use and why?

Which is more preferable to use?

Comment: "d" for "the"? "y" for "why"? You'll get better responses here if you have some respect for the other users and use correct spelling, grammar, punctuation, capitalisation, etc.

Comment: Again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059617/network-intrusion-detection-system-in-java

Comment: If what X does is only sniffing packets sent over LAN, you can't detect it.

Comment: ok..what if he modifies d packet over the LAN..can that be detected..?if yes then how..?

Comment: Vote to close as exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059617/network-intrusion-detection-system-in-java

Answer (score 3):

It appears development has stopped on Jpcap. Their last release was 2007. In contrast, jNetPcap has had very recent releases. The underlying libpcap C library that they both wrap has continued to evolve, so I would go with jNetPcap for that reason.

On the other hand, libpcap is a fairly simple API. If you are comfortable with C, then you may gain performance advantages by using the library directly instead of going through a Java wrapper. Something to consider, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One simple idea I've had for network intrusion was to listen for messages on the braodcast IP address.  New comers to the network may likely need an IP address from the DHCP server. If this is so, then they will have to send out a broadcast that a DHCP server will respond to .  You could write a program that sits on client A and displays popups whenever it hears something on the broadcast address.

Comment: but how wil that make it a intrusion system..?
i didnt get u darren..
can u please elaborate on what u said..

Comment: Not a bad idea for detection new clients on the network, but it wont of course protect anything against malicious software on the client...

Answer (score 0):

If it's still an issue, use .NET version [jnetpcap](http://jnetpcap.com/). I built a NIDS for a master's term project and I tried to use Java and get jpcap and similar working but it was near impossible. So I went for the most viable option c# and it worked alot easier, even thought I didn't know it then.

Also use [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/) since you will need to use [weka.jar](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) from .NET as well.